# Pixelate / blur parts of image using an image mask

Tags: mask, blur, graphicsmagick, pixelate

I need to pixelate parts of an image using an mask image in tif format.

In ImageMagick there are multiple options to do it, for example:

```
convert -quality 100 source.tif \( -clone 0 -resize 16% -scale 3840x2160! \) \( unsharp_mask.tif \) -composite result.tif
```

The source image and the unsharp_mask image have the same size: 3840 x 2160

The unsharp_mask image is filled black except the areas which need to pixelated, they are white, in the source image.

How can I do it with GraphicsMagick?

Is there a simple way to achieve the same result?

Comment: You may get better results using -scale 16% rather than -resize 16%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Well... with some time spent *"dinking around"*, err, I mean assiduously studying the options, I come up with this which is both faster and also obviates the need for any intermediate files:

```
cat - <<EOF | gm batch -prompt off
convert source.tif -resize 8x -scale 400x MPR:pixellated
convert -size 400x400 xc:white  -fill black  -draw "circle 200,200 200,400" MPR:mask
composite source.tif MPR:pixellated MPR:mask result.tif
EOF
```

It produces the same result as below. If anyone is interested, **MPR** means *"Memory Program Register"* and it is basically a chunk of RAM with a name.

**Original Answer**

There may be a simpler method that you could work out by dinking around for ages, but this seems to do what I think you want.

This is my source image `source.tif` and it is 400x400px:

[image]

I pixellate it like this:

```
gm convert source.tif -resize 8x -scale 400x pixellated.tif
```

[image]

Then I make a mask like this - I have artificially added a red outline so you can see the extent on StackOverflow's white background:

```
gm convert -size 400x400 xc:white  -fill black  -draw "circle 200,200 200,400" mask.tif
```

[image]

And do the final composite like this:

```
gm composite source.tif pixellated.tif mask.tif result.tif
```

[image]

By the way, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220630/2836621) for some thoughts on **GraphicsMagick** vs **ImageMagick**.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. I have to redo my old masks because they are negated and not compatible (I think it has something to do with LZW compression) but it works. Normally I use big source images > 2 GB so I have to test the performance. Anyway I'm glad you showed me a way to do it with GM. Thanks!