# imagemagick wmf support on Alpine Linux

Tags: imagemagick, alpine-linux

I am installing imagemagick on Alpine, which picks up 7.0.10 version of imagemagick.

My primary use is to covert WMF to PNG.
But `convert sample.wmf sample.png` gives error

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `WMF' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/572.
convert: no images defined `sample.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3322.
```

As per https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php, I also installed libwmf, which does not resolve the issue.

`identify -list format | grep WMF` does not return any result.

Comment: I have updated my answer - please have another look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You are in luck! **GraphicsMagick** can do it on `alpine:latest`:

```
apk add graphicsmagick

gm identify -version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.36 20201226 Q16 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2020 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe         yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)     yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)    yes
  BZIP                       no
  DPS                        no
  FlashPix                   no
  FreeType                   yes
  Ghostscript (Library)      no
  JBIG                       no
  JPEG-2000                  no
  JPEG                       yes
  Little CMS                 no
  Loadable Modules           yes
  Solaris mtmalloc           no
  Google perftools tcmalloc  no
  OpenMP                     no
  PNG                        yes
  TIFF                       yes
  TRIO                       no
  Solaris umem               no
  WebP                       yes
  WMF                        yes        <--- HERE IT IS
  X11                        no
  XML                        yes
  ZLIB                       yes
```

Now do the conversion from WMF to PNG:

```
gm convert sample.wmf result.png
```

---

**Original Answer**

I don't think you'll be able to do that, with **ImageMagick** at least...

I tried installing `libwmf` on `alpine:latest` and then installing **ImageMagick** from source and it declined to use `libwmf` v0.2.12

So I checked what **ImageMagick** requires and it wants `libwmf` v0.2.8.2.

So I tried `alpine:3.8` which can install `libwmf` v0.2.8.4 but **ImageMagick** still wouldn't accept that (xxx/ipa.h is missing).

So I looked back to `alpine:3.3` and `alpine:3.4` and they have no `libwmf`.

So I tried `alpine:3.5` and that was the same `libwmf` version as alpine:3.8

TLDR; alpine:3.5's `libwmf` is too new for **ImageMagick** and `alpine:3.4` doesn't have `libwmf` at all.

**Note**: I found the packages and versions of `libwmf` on [this](https://repology.org/project/libwmf/versions) website.

Comment: Just to clarify... I am not suggesting anybody do a full installation of `aline:lates`, rather I am suggesting `docker`, i.e. `docker run -it alpine:latest`