# Find Color percentage in a Image through GraphicsMagic

Tags: image, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

So all my images are pdf and tiff and saved in database. I want to accept images which has only light color like signature in red/blue but no colorful logo or things like that.
I was able to get somewhere closer throw Imagemagick.

In order to increase speed of a conversion, and avoid bugs, I'd like to convert the following ImageMagick command to a GraphicsMagick command.

```
   convert filename.pdf -colorspace HSI -channel g +channel -format "%[fx:mean.g]" info:
```

I noticed that we don't have similar mean function in graphicsmagick. But Can we do something similar through graphics magick? TIA.

Comment: Sure, but why do you think GM will be faster? And if you are interested in performance, why aren't you using `libvips`, or **OpenCV**? And you don't mention your Operating System, or environment...

Comment: This may be relevant... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220630/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell - We did compare the results and decided to use GraphicsMagic for  our project. I looked into libvips after you mention and something we can use too but didn't find any option to achieve what I am looking. Any insights will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are trying to find the mean Saturation of an image in HSI colourspace.

If so, your **ImageMagick** command is unnecessarily verbose, you just need:

```
magick INPUTIMAGE -colorspace HSL -format "%[fx:mean.g]" info:
```

There is no need to select the second Green/Saturation channel wit `-channel g` because you already select that with the `[fx:mean.g]` operator and there is no need to revert to the default channels afterwards with `+channel` because you don't care about them anyway.

---

Moving on to a **GraphicsMagick** version - it is not strictly possible because GM doesn't support HSI colourspace, only HSL. So, let us assume you are happy enough with the mean Saturation of an HSL image instead, you can do something horrible like this with **GraphicsMagick** to get it:

```
{ echo convert INPUTIMAGE -colorspace HSL -channel green MPR:x; echo identify -verbose MPR:x ; } | gm batch -prompt off | grep -i mean
Mean:                    14329.41 (0.2187)
```

Or, alternative syntax:

```
cat <<EOF | gm batch -prompt off | grep -i mean
convert a.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel green MPR:x
identify -verbose MPR:x
EOF
```

There may be easier, less arcane ways of doing this, I don't really know **GraphicsMagick** that well.