# non-file image types in GraphicsMagick

Tags: graphics, graphicsmagick

I recently discovered the existence in `GraphicksMagick` of image types that are not actual image files. For instance, here is an excerpt of a `gm batch` script I am using to time-stamp and mask a series of images for a video:

```
convert -font helvetica -fill black -pointsize 48 label:"2 days, 7:31:42" mpr:label
convert -crop 1616x1769+0+0 movies/worm7/sim7aseed123456/plot-1_199902.png mpr:cropped
composite movies/worm7/maskmatte.png mpr:cropped mpr:masked
composite -gravity North mpr:label mpr:masked movies/worm7/scratch/plot-1_199902.png
convert -font helvetica -fill black -pointsize 48 label:"2 days, 7:33:22" mpr:label
convert -crop 1616x1769+0+0 movies/worm7/sim7aseed123456/plot-1_200002.png mpr:cropped
composite movies/worm7/maskmatte.png mpr:cropped mpr:masked
composite -gravity North mpr:label mpr:masked movies/worm7/scratch/plot-1_200002.png
```

That's eight lines from an 8000 line script that processes 2000 input images. The images whose names end in `.png` are of course real image files. However, in this script I also use two types of images that don't correspond to any file. `label:"2 days, 7:33:22"` refers to an image created by rendering that text in the font specified by options. `mpr:label`, `mpr:cropped`, and `mpr:masked` are intermediate results that are held in working memory during execution of the script, avoiding the need to create temporary files.

My questions are two: First, are there any other such non-file image types that `GraphicsMagick` recognizes? Second, are these documented anywhere?

I found `label:` and `mpr:` mentioned in some `gm` examples that I googled up pretty much at random. They are super-useful, so I'd like to know what else I'm missing.

To forestall a particular type of answer I don't need: Yes, I am aware of the list of image formats in the gm man page, and of this text:

```
   To read the "built-in" formats (GRANITE, H, LOGO, NETSCAPE, PLASMA, and
   ROSE) use a prefix (including the colon) without a filename or  suffix.
   To read the XC format, follow the colon with a color specification.  To
   read the CAPTION format, follow the colon with a text string or with  a
   filename prefixed with the at symbol (@).
```

But I have not found anywhere in the man pages an answer to my questions.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many are supported by **GraphicsMagick**, but there are lists of **ImageMagick** pseudo-image formats [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#pseudo)

You may want to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220630/2836621) too.