# How to get print of coordinates for Connected components labeling in GraphicsMagick?

Tags: graphicsmagick

Is there a way to scan the image pixel by pixel and print the coordinates of each pixel regions by color? similiar to this ImageMagick´s feature [Uniquely Label Connected Regions](https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php). I'd like to do it in bash or python to identify the coordinates of several rectangles inside an image, each rectangle is of different color or has a border line of some color. I asked this in superuser before. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1828262/connected-components-labeling-in-graphicsmagick)

Example how this can be done in ImageMagick.

```
magick objects.gif -connected-components 4 -auto-level -depth 8 objects.png

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 256x171+0+0 119.2,80.8 33117 srgb(0,0,0)
  2: 120x135+104+18 159.5,106.5 8690 srgb(255,255,255)
  3: 50x36+129+44 154.2,63.4 1529 srgb(0,0,0)
  4: 21x23+0+45 8.8,55.9 409 srgb(255,255,255)
  1: 4x10+252+0 253.9,4.1 31 srgb(255,255,255)
```

**UPDATE**

Consider this input image.

[image]

I have a kind of large IM script in bash that detects dynamically the coordinates of the rectangles with charts and the small rectangles at the top (blue, red, green, purple). First converts to black and white the input image and prints the coordinates. Then I use the output of this script to crop all the rectangles for a further processing. The thing is takes some time to make all the processes and for what I found recently, graphicsmagick claims to be faster.

```
convert 'input.png' \
         -transparent "#FFFFFF" \
         -transparent "#27A9E3" \
         -transparent "#28B779" \
         -transparent "#E7191B" \
         -transparent "#852B99" \
         -alpha extract -negate \
         -define connected-components:verbose=true \
         -define connected-components:mean-color=true \
         -define connected-components:area-threshold=5000 \
         -connected-components 8 black_and_white.png
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do ultimately? Please add a representative image so we can see what you are talking about. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that GraphicsMagick even has connected components processing. But Python/OpenCV does have connected components.  Ask in that forum.

Comment: @MarkSetchell please see my update in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to work out **GraphicsMagick** doesn't provide *"Connected Components"* processing...

1. See my answer [What's the Difference between GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220630/2836621)

---

2. Look at the online manual, [here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html), search for the word *"connected"* and discover it isn't there.

---

3. Download and unpack the latest source code from September 2023 and search all the files for the word *"connected"* and come up empty:

   `find GraphicsMagick-1.3.42 -type f -exec grep -i connected {} \;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, I'll continue with ImageMagick that have features almost for everything, only I was trying to look for a faster solution since my whole script takes about 1 min to finish

Comment: What percentage of your 1 minute is spent on the `convert` command in your question? And are you using that command on multiple images in your script? And what OS are you using?

Comment: The first convert command to get coordinates of black and white pixels regions of a single image that has 28 rectangle and is a bit larger than the image I shared. It takes about 40 seconds to get the coordinates. I'm primeraly run it in Cygwin (under windows 11). The conert

Comment: You could try scaling, using `-scale 25%` maybe, the image down by a factor of 2 (or 4) before running *"connected components"* and seeing if that's faster and being a few pixels out in your locations matters.

Comment: If your image is always vertically split down the middle, you could crop into two halves and process the two halves in parallel.

Comment: I'll try, your suggestion processing in halves and scaling. Probably would be faster in that way. thanks so much for the help.