# How to get image red green blue standard deviation values from gm identify -verbose?

Tags: php, regex, grep, zsh, graphicsmagick

I am trying to get the values given for `Standard Deviation` in the `Red`, `Green`, and `Blue` channels that you can see in `gm identity -verbose` but they're not listed in the `-format` options.

How can I get these from the commandline?

A workaround to list the values using PHP:

```php
    $raw = `gm identify -verbose {$file}|grep -E -e '^ +(Standard Deviation): *[^b]*$'`;
    preg_match_all("/(?<=Standard Deviation:)(?: +)([\d\.]+)/", $raw, $matches);
    $ret = [$matches[1][0], $matches[1][1], $matches[1][2]];
```

this is the output from `gm identify -verbose`.
**Example** we need the values from properties under `Channel Statistics`:

```
Image: /.../.../img.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Geometry: 1064x1600
  Class: DirectClass
  Type: true color
  Depth: 8 bits-per-pixel component
  Channel Depths:
    Red:      8 bits
    Green:    8 bits
    Blue:     8 bits
  Channel Statistics:
    Red:
      Minimum:                     0.00 (0.0000)
      Maximum:                   255.00 (1.0000)
      Mean:                      132.32 (0.5189)
      Standard Deviation:         45.92 (0.1801)
    Green:
      Minimum:                     0.00 (0.0000)
      Maximum:                   255.00 (1.0000)
      Mean:                      104.17 (0.4085)
      Standard Deviation:         55.13 (0.2162)
    Blue:
      Minimum:                     0.00 (0.0000)
      Maximum:                   255.00 (1.0000)
      Mean:                      103.61 (0.4063)
      Standard Deviation:         55.71 (0.2185)
  Filesize: 452.0Ki
  Interlace: No
  Orientation: Unknown
  Background Color: white
  Border Color: #DFDFDF
  Matte Color: #BDBDBD
  Page geometry: 1064x1600+0+0
  Compose: Over
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  JPEG-Quality: 95
  JPEG-Colorspace: 2
  JPEG-Colorspace-Name: RGB
  JPEG-Sampling-factors: 2x2,1x1,1x1
  Signature: 136912e901ae9314fd683868418cae1f5d838c6891ddd8c13ce28057fb39365a
  Tainted: False
  User Time: 0.010u
  Elapsed Time: 0m:0.014459s
  Pixels Per Second: 112.3Mi
```

Comment: Why is this tagged zsh? You are not using zsh anywhere.

Comment: [edit] your question to show the output of `gm identity -verbose` if you want us to help you write some code to parse that output.

Comment: @user1934428 because zsh is what I'm trying to find a solution for, the php was a workaround that is actually fine I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU Grep`, where `-o` prints only the matched parts and `-P` for Perl-compatible regular expressions:

```
grep -oP "\bStandard Deviation:\h+\K\d[\d.]*"
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bStandard Deviation:` Match literally starting with a word boundary
- `\h+` Match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\d[\d.]*` Match a single digit followed by optional digits or dots (or `[\d.]+` but note that it could also only match dots

You might also use `[\d.]+` but that could also match dots only. Using `\.?\d[\d.]*` could match an optional leading dot, or a more strict format not allowing consecutive dots `\.?\d+(?:\.\d+)*\b`

See the [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/FE7pty/1).

---

Or an alternative using `sed`

```
sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]\+Standard Deviation:[[:space:]]\+\([[:digit:]][[:digit:].]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: I missed the `\K` in the manual, that's awesome! One thing, if i wanted to match more do alternations work? like `grep -oP "\b(Minimum|Maximum|Standard Deviation):\h+\K\d[\d.]*"`? I'll try it but was wondering if we sould edit the Q&A to include that?

Comment: grep: invalid option -- P
usage: grep [-abcdDEFGHhIiJLlMmnOopqRSsUVvwXxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: how do i use **GNU** grep instead of standard grep? i'm on macos with macports if I need to install it

Comment: @yarns on macos you can use `ggrep`

Comment: @Thefourthbird only if they install it first, MacOS doesn't come with gnu coreutils pre-installed AFAIK.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I installed coreutils @9.4 (sysutils) via macports but `ggrep` or `coreutils` isn't there i tried `which ggrep`. also can't find where the installs for `port` are, i used to know, had a look around `/opt/local/` `/usr/local` .... also the port info doesn't say much. having a brain drain moment :S

Comment: @yarns On my mac I installed grep like this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193288/how-to-install-and-use-gnu-grep-in-macos Did the `sed` solution work out?

Comment: i found i had `pcre2grep` who knows how that got installed but it worked with `for f in *.jpg; do echo $f;gm identify -verbose $f|pcre2grep -o --allow-lookaround-bsk "\b(Minimum|Maximum|Standard Deviation):\h+\K\d[\d.]*"; done`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tried `gm identify -verbose 'image.jpg'|sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]\+Standard Deviation:[[:space:]]\+\([[:digit:]][[:digit:].]*\).*/\1/p'` but it returned nothing (stdout was blank) also in my php script it returned null

Answer (score 1):

If using **ImageMagick** as opposed to **GraphicsMagick** is an option - see [What's the Difference Between ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56220630/2836621) - then you have more flexibility.

You can print like this:

```
magick result.png -format "%[fx:standard_deviation.r]\n%[fx:standard_deviation.g]\n%[fx:standard_deviation.b]" info:   
    
0.399446
0.319672
0.213623
```

Or you can get **ImageMagick** to output in JSON and use `jq` to parse out the fields you want:

```
magick result.png json: | jq -r '.[].image.channelStatistics | "\(.red.standardDeviation) \(.green.standardDeviation) \(.blue.standardDeviation)"'

101.859 81.5164 54.4738
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me on macos was based on the answer from @thefourthbird. I couldn't install `ggrep` but had success with `pcre2grep` from `port` (macports).

```
gm identify -verbose img.jpg|\
pcre2grep -o --allow-lookaround-bsk "\b(?:Minimum|Maximum|Mean|Standard Deviation): +\d+\.\d+ \(\K\d+\.\d+"
```

the `--allow-lookaround-bsk` option in `pcre2grep` enabled the `\K` symbol which was needed to discard the content before each value.

The result is the extracted values I can use from the example in the question:

```
0.0000
1.0000
0.5189
0.1801
0.0000
1.0000
0.4085
0.2162
0.0000
1.0000
0.4063
0.2185
```

**Note**: the number of values varies.

- monochrome images only have 1 channel
- color images (see example) have 3 for red, green, and blue.
- each channel will always have 4 values: `Minimum`|`Maximum`|`Mean`|`Standard Deviation`